# keyboard library interfered with python input

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard

When I press on "p" it triggers input with "p" in the start :

```
import keyboard

def print_your_name():
    x = input("Enter Your Name: ")
    print(x)



keyboard.add_hotkey('p', print_your_name)
keyboard.wait("esc")
```

output:

```
Enter Your Name:p
```

Is there any way to send a clean input to the user?

Comment: do you mean just `input()`? it won't have any input prompt otherwise you can add a newline (perhaps just `print()` or embedding `\n` in a line)

Comment: That doesn't work still adds 'p' from the keyboard hotkey

Comment: if you want to swallow the input, you need to control the input and output streams - what operating system are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preventing key presses from appearing on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49578801/preventing-key-presses-from-appearing-on-screen)

Comment: In general: do no mix different input (and output) modules. If you go with `keyboard`, uses only it. Why? both need to keep status and bookkeeping, but in a independent way, so you risk to have inconsistent status. Just implement `input` with keyboard (if a key is not enter: add to string (but if it is backspace, delete it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to use the built-in `msvcrt` library (on Windows). If you use a Unix-like system there is a library called `termios` that I believe will do the same thing although I have not tested it. Just replace `msvcrt` wherever it appears in the code with `termios`.

Here is the working code

```
import msvcrt

def print_your_name():
    x = input("Enter Your Name: ")
    print(x)

def listen_for_p():
    while True:
        #Wait for keypress
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            key = msvcrt.getch().decode()
            if key == 'p':
                print_your_name()

# Start listening for 'p' key
listen_for_p()
```

This approach directly captures keypresses from the console and doesn't rely on hooking into system-wide keyboard events, which interferes with the `input()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Please let me know if there is anything I can do to improve this answer.

Instead of trying to send a clean input to the user, I recommend simply making the p go away, by making a virtual keypress. For example, using the press() function included in the keyboard module:

```
import keyboard

def print_your_name():
    keyboard.press('backspace') #this gets rid of the p
    x = input("Enter Your Name: ")
    print(x)

keyboard.add_hotkey('p', print_your_name)
keyboard.wait("esc")
```

As a sidenote, the keypress happens instantly, so the user won't see the p at all when the program runs. Here, I decided to use the keyboard module since you were already using it to detect the keypress, but there are other modules you can use such as pyautogui or pynput, although I think that it isn't necessary in this situation. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: That works but I should clarify that when the user presses on other hotkeys to trigger other functions and then he presses 'p' it logs all the pressed hotkeys, I needed a way to clear out all input so it gives the user a clean input eventually

Comment: @MarkWasfy, I do not understand what you mean by "it logs all the pressed hotkeys", could you clarify?